# How to force a Web Api method to return date with a format like this: /Date(46546)/

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, jquery-jtable

I'm migrating an old application and I need that a specific web api 2 method returns date like this: `/Date(46546)/` and not in the ISO 8601 format:  `2016-10-31T07:22:57.1153868-05:00`

My web api method looks like:

```
[Route("GetListData/{jtStartIndex:int=0}/{jtPageSize:int=0}/{jtSorting?}")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetListData(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
{
    try
    {
        var dataList = DataContainer.Instance.Data;
        //HERE dataList is a collection of a custom model, a model that have properties of datetime type.

        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
            new { Result = "OK", Records = dataList, TotalRecordCount = dataList.Count });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, newer WebAPI uses JSON.NET as the serializer by default, which adheres to the JSON standard and thus cannot serialize the format you requested, which is not JSON standard compliant.

Old WebAPI used Microsoft's own DataContractJsonSerializer, which only supports the non-standard-compliant format.

To get back to that serializer:

First, [you have to add a serializer to your WebAPI project](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/mar/09/using-an-alternate-json-serializer-in-aspnet-web-api#DataContractJsonSerializersucks), at the end of the list of available serializers, which uses the old serializer library.

Then you  you [can select that very serializer for a certain controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383035/asp-net-web-api-controller-specific-serializer).